# No WCF Message security with certificate in windows store apps?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-store-apps, certificate, wcf-security

we run a WCF service that has the following security settings:

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
       <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
       <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

I have to use this WCF service from a Windows Store App. As I figured out there is no wsHttpBinding at all.

Anyway, how can I use certificate authentication as message security?

Usually I can use

```
DatabaseService.DatabaseServiceClient client = new DatabaseService.DatabaseServiceClient();
..
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(..);
```

but there is only "UserName", "Windows" and "HttpDigest" under ClientCredentials in the API for Windows Store Apps.

Thank you

Comment: From [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - "The following client credential types are supported in Windows Store applications :   None, Basic, Digest, Negotiate, NTLM, Windows, Username (Message Security),Windows (Transport Security)" -  but not Certificate.

Comment: I am not sure whether this can solve your issue. Can you try creating an external library to access the service and then accessing that library in your Windows Store App?